# How to go directly to a certain sheet when you open a google spreadsheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps

I want my spreadsheet to open at a certain sheet. I've tried the following but it still just opens the first sheet.

```
function setActiveSheetToday(){
    var date = new Date();
    var sheet = getSheetByDate(date); //custom function that returns sheet object
    var SS = sheet.getParent();
    SS.setActiveSheet(sheet);
}
```

Then I make an `onOpen` trigger.

```
ScriptApp.newTrigger('setActiveSheetToday').forSpreadsheet(SS_ID).onOpen().create();
```

When I open the spreadsheet, it still opens at the first sheet. Any suggestions?

*EDIT*

I think I found the reason why it doesn't work here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound#special_methods

So it apparently only works for bounded scripts..

Comment: There is no method named `getSheetByDate()`

Answer (score 1):

You could make the sheet you want to open on the first sheet. Just add `SS.moveActiveSheet(1);` to your `setActiveSheetToday()` function.

Alternatively, activating a sheet from a bound script changes the focus as you want. Doing it from a separate script file doesn't appear to.

Comment: Moving the sheet to the first place isn't really a viable option in my project. Is there a way to bound a script to a spreadsheet with code? Otherwise I have to manually add the script to every spreadsheet.

Comment: If you are copying a spreadsheet with a bound script then the bound script will copy with it, but I'm not sure of a way to alter it from a script running elsewhere.

It would be a bit clunky, but you could possibly have a spreadsheet with an `onOpen()` function that activates a sheet named in a hidden sheet, then build whatever you are making on a copy of that spreadsheet, and write the name of the sheet to open to the relevant place.

It would be a lot easier to just move the sheet to the front though - what is the sheet order affecting that you don't want to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the object, your sheet?

You may try this function for simple testing:

```
function onOpen() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  ss.setActiveSheet(sheet);
}
```

make sheet called "Sheet1", go to any other sheet and reload the page.

for your code I suggest the test:

```
Logger.log(sheet.getName());
```

Comment: The function `getSheetByDate()` works, that's not the issue. I think you assume that I'm using a script coupled to a spreadsheet, that's not the case, I'm using an independent script file. That's why I use `forSpreadsheet(SS_ID).onOpen()`.